# Apache Camel Spring webservices SpringWebserviceConsumer does not read answer from in if not out

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, apache-camel, spring-ws

I use Camel spring-ws component to expose SOAP web service by specifying it in the 'from' part of the route.

It happens to be, that at the end of the route logic, the 'out' message of Exchange is not populated, however the 'in' message contains desired response data.

Default convention for producer component is to use 'in' message of exchange if 'out' is not present when generating final response.

SpringWebserviceConsumer however only supports scenario when final exchange has the 'out' message.
Here is the snippet of code from https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-spring-ws/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/spring/ws/SpringWebserviceConsumer.java:

```
public void invoke(MessageContext messageContext) throws Exception {
    Exchange exchange = getEndpoint().createExchange(ExchangePattern.InOptionalOut);
    populateExchangeFromMessageContext(messageContext, exchange);

    // start message processing
    getProcessor().process(exchange);

    if (exchange.getException() != null) {
        throw exchange.getException();
    } else if (exchange.getPattern().isOutCapable()) {
        Message responseMessage = exchange.getOut(Message.class);
        if (responseMessage != null) {
            Source responseBody = responseMessage.getBody(Source.class);
            WebServiceMessage response = messageContext.getResponse();

            configuration.getMessageFilter().filterConsumer(exchange, response);

            XmlConverter xmlConverter = configuration.getXmlConverter();
            xmlConverter.toResult(responseBody, response.getPayloadResult());
        }
    }
}
```

This results in no response generated to the SOAP request.

Question:
Is this a bug/limitation of camel-spring-ws or I'm not using the spring-ws consumer correctly?

Otherwise, it sounds like I have to explicitly set the exchange patter to InOut?

Comment: Is there a reason why you explicitly create your exchange with the "InOptionalOut" exchange pattern instead of "InOut"? WS-operations typically expect a response unless they've been set to "InOnly".

Comment: Why do you set the exchange pattern? You can use the default pattern of InOnly.

Comment: Updated description to include reference to camel-spring-ws SpringWebserviceConsumer class, it is not my code.

Comment: Yeah that code is a bit wrong, you are welcome to log a JIRA

Comment: I logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10888

Answer (score 0):

Until CAMEL-10888 is released, as a work-around, in the route, you can set the exchange pattern to InOut to get not-null 'out' message of Exchange:

```
.setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
```